# Electron: Storing a value securely

Tags: node.js, database, encryption, electron

I have developed an application with Node.js. Since I'm planning on selling this application, I have implemented an account system with the help of firebase. However, the user should not login everytime it closes the app.

Is there any way to securely safe a (boolean) value, to check if the user is logged in (without internet)?

In the past I've used node-json-db but it can be easily read and manipulated.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Let me know if you have any other approaches for that problem.

Comment: keep on `localStorage`

Comment: failed to mention that I want it to check the login status in the main process before the electron app starts since i have two different windows for the login and main app.

Comment: Secure from whom? The user is in control of their device. You can't stop them from modifying the information on their own device.

Comment: In this case you must first encrypt logged data then store on json-db.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I dont want the user to 'crack' my program. I will also protect my source code but the user can still modify the database. Thats why Im looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Metalik Do you know any good module for encryption? And wont the user be able to easily decrypt the data and encrypt it again with modified information?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_crypto.asp

Comment: It isn't possible to stop a user from modifying the information on their own device.  If you encrypt it, and the key to decrypt is also on the device (even in your source), then the user can decrypt the information.  What you want to do isn't possible *unless* a server is involved.